# tiktok https://open.tiktokapis.com/v2/oauth/token/ Error：invalid_grant

Tags: oauth, tiktok

```
curl --location 'https://open.tiktokapis.com/v2/oauth/token/' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
--data-urlencode 'client_key=xxxxxx' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=xxxxxx' \
--data-urlencode 'code=xxxxxx' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
--data-urlencode 'redirect_uri=https://xxxx'
```

I use v2 api want to get token, but the response is always error:
{
"error": "invalid_grant",
"error_description": "Authorization code is expired.",
"log_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
}

I use the same process, but I can obtain tokens using the v1 interface

Has anyone encountered this kind of error? I sent an email to TikTok, but I didn't receive a response